# android issue with ViewPagerIndicator in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am implementing ViewPagerIndicator  in my app. Like in `google+` after pressing `Stream on Dashboard` its going to 3 view pages like `NearBy`, `All Circles`, `Incoming`.

I am able to get this output in my application. But like `google+` when we ll go to `NearBy` its automatically fetches the gps location, but if at same time u ll go to  `All Circles` then that previous fetching stops and control works for that page.

My question is at the time of sliding how can i stop the 1st page view (`NearBy`) when it ll go to the next page view (`All Circles`).

Plz anybody help me.

Thank you